# Filling data via series AutoFill without dragging

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-2003

It's been quite some time since I used a spreadsheet product. In Excel 2003 there was a series autofill feature. I don't mean the "enter two numbers, highlight, and drag" feature. There was a way to bring up a menu, alt-e-i-s if my muscle memory recalls correctly, that would let you specify a start value, end value and step value. It was incredibly useful.

I really could use this feature in Google sheets. I've been searching for the last 15 minutes and can not find it anywhere. I also checked and it looks like this might not be a feature in MS excel anymore, either. Does anyone know if either product can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `SEQUENCE` function in Google Sheets

```
=SEQUENCE(11,1,6,2)
```

[image]

Please read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)

Comment: Glad I could help. Thank you for taking the time to accept.